# Find the manager_id with most people under supervision

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am having trouble displaying the most people under `manager_id`. The answer is `manager_id = 100` but I can't seem to make a sql that displays it. Below are 2 tables that were created and given to me.

```
CREATE TABLE departments
    ( department_id    NUMBER(4)
    , department_name  VARCHAR2(30)
    CONSTRAINT  dept_name_nn  NOT NULL
    , manager_id       NUMBER(6)
    , location_id      NUMBER(4)
    ) ;

CREATE TABLE employees
    ( employee_id    NUMBER(6)
    , first_name     VARCHAR2(20)
    , last_name      VARCHAR2(25)
     CONSTRAINT     emp_last_name_nn  NOT NULL
    , email          VARCHAR2(25)
    CONSTRAINT     emp_email_nn  NOT NULL
    , phone_number   VARCHAR2(20)
    , hire_date      DATE
    CONSTRAINT     emp_hire_date_nn  NOT NULL
    , job_id         VARCHAR2(10)
    CONSTRAINT     emp_job_nn  NOT NULL
    , salary         NUMBER(8,2)
    , commission_pct NUMBER(2,2)
    , manager_id     NUMBER(6)
    , department_id  NUMBER(4)
    , CONSTRAINT     emp_salary_min
                     CHECK (salary > 0) 
    , CONSTRAINT     emp_email_uk
                     UNIQUE (email)
    ) ;
```

Below is my code where I am trying to join the two tables `employees` and `departments` together to find `manager_id` between them with the most occurrence.

Every time I try to run my sql block it gives me an error like `"ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"` or something is wrong with `Limit 1`

```
SELECT COUNT(Manager_id) into v_manager_id, 
FROM departments d
RIGHT JOIN employees e
ON d.manager_id = e.manager_id
GROUP BY Manager_id
ORDER BY COUNT(Manager_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Where [in the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) did you find that `LIMIT 1` is valid?

Comment: "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined tips. ... Cause: A column name used in a join exists in more than one table and is thus referenced ambiguously. In a join, any column name that occurs in more than one of the tables must be prefixed by its table name when referenced."

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ever since Oracle took over MySQL, googling for Oracle syntax has become tough. :-/ I'ts like googling what a stack overflow means. |-(

Answer (score 0):

You should rather select count(employee_id) ... group by manager_id so for all employees who are under some manager that count is displayed and then check if that count is max under that manager or not 
else it is alias or qualifier issue you should name manager_id as some alias.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select manager_id 
from (select manager_id,count(*)  
      from employees  
      group by manager_id 
      order by 
      count(*) desc)
where rownum<=1 ;
```

you can also use nested subquery like this:

```
create table ns_231(col1 number,col2 number);

insert into ns_231 values(1,1);
insert into ns_231 values(2,3);
insert into ns_231 values(3,3);
insert into ns_231 values(1,2);
insert into ns_231 values(2,5);
insert into ns_231 values(2,1);
insert into ns_231 values(3,1);
insert into ns_231 values(1,4);

SELECT * FROM ns_231;
commit;
select col1 from (select col1,count(*) from ns_231  group by col1 order by count(*) desc) where rownum<=1 ;

select col1 from ns_231 group by col1
having count(*)=(select max(total) from (select count(*) as total from 
ns_231 group by col1));
```

output:

```
1
2
```

for your table the query is :

```
select manager_id from employees group by manager_id
having count(*)=(select max(total) from (select count(*) as total from 
employees group by manager_id));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need  to add qualifier to `manager_id` because it occurs in both tables

```
SELECT COUNT(d.Manager_id) into v_manager_id, 
FROM departments d
RIGHT JOIN employees e
ON d.manager_id = e.manager_id
GROUP BY d.Manager_id
ORDER BY COUNT(d.Manager_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```